# Should I explicitly declare the range after such that in a set?

Tags: notation

$S = \{(a_k)_{k = 0}^{2} \mid a_{i + 1} - a_i = 1\}$ is a set of infinite elements, and each element is consist of a 3-tuple in which an element is increased by $1$ than the previous one. However, should I explicitly declare the range after such that in the set to be $S = \{(a_k)_{k = 0}^{2} \mid a_{i + 1} - a_i = 1 , \forall 0 \leqslant i < 2\}$? In my opinion, the previous $S$ is clear enough and does not produce any ambiguity. Is there any regulation about this?

Comment: 1. In your second set definition shouldn't it be $0\leq i <2$? 2. In your first definition it is not clear, if there exist succh $i$, or if it is for all $i$. 3. Notation $A=\{(a-1, a, a+1)| a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is clearer

Comment: 1. Yes, it's an off-by-one error. 2. Is it okay to just add $, \forall i$ (nothing after it)? 3. This is a shortened example. The original one is not that simple to write something similar to your suggestion.

Comment: If the context is clear and there is no room for ambiguity or confusion, then yes, it is okay to use shorthand notation. However, the first way you wrote this opens up ambiguities (Why are they taking the square of each $(a_k)$?) and confusions (Why does the index change from $k$ to $i$?) and so some changes are definitely appropriate.